# heap memory snapshot on a kubernetes cluster nodejs

Tags: kubernetes, node.js, eks, javascript

I'm using node.js application on a kubernetes cluster (EKS).
When there is a lot of workload on the application it reaches the maximum heap size that is allocated and pods get restarted.
I'm looking for a tool to be able to save a snapshot or dump files before my pods restarting to find the root cause.
I'll be happy to provide more information if needed, Thanks !